# Cannot find module 'yarn' even though Yarn is installed

Tags: angular, yarnpkg, angular-universal

I am trying to run the starter kit of universal from this link: https://github.com/ng-seed/universal and even though I have followed the steps and installed Yarn, when I run the command to run the server, it gives me the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'yarn'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
> at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
> at DllBundlesControl.getPackageJsonPath (/home/themadhatter/sites/brandyd-relaunch/node_modules/src/DllBundlesControl.ts:237:39)
> at DllBundlesControl.getPackageJson (/home/themadhatter/sites/brandyd-relaunch/node_modules/src/DllBundlesControl.ts:224:32)

.
.
.

When I run the command 'yarn' in my directory, it gives me the following message:
yarn install v1.0.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 2.10s.

I tried Googling and there are errors of missing other packages, but no errors of yarn itself missing. I can see where the module is missing in the error, but I can't seem to understand why it is not able to recursively get to the yarn module even though it's installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you install yarn by doing `npm install yarn -g` - this will install yarn globally on your machine, failing that you can use npm to install the packages by doing `npm install`, this will have the same effect as doing `yarn install`.

Answer (score 8):

If you're facing the same issue, check if there is `yarnrc.yml` file in your project root directory then delete it. Then run `yarn install` again.

Answer (score 1):

1.change the path of `yarn` in `~/.zshrc` or other config file.etc

2.open your cmd/shell input `open ~/.zshrc` ,then config file will be opened

3.change the path like `/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/bin/yarn`

[image]

4.in file `/.zshrc` input like
`` export PATH="$PATH:`/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/bin/yarn`" ``

5.return your cmd/shell, input `source ~/.zshrc` makes config file works

6.then, input `yarn --version`, output info of yarn, it's woks !!!

Comment: more detail can look it: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5349#issuecomment-714908143